# Reset Animation from previous page

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

I have page transition animation where all elements move upwards (slide up) and then go to `SearchPage`...

```
@override
  void initState() {

    super.initState();
    controller =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(seconds: 1));
    offset = Tween<Offset>(begin: Offset.zero, end: Offset(0.0, -2.0))
        .animate(controller);

    offset2 = Tween<Offset>(begin: Offset.zero, end: Offset(0.0, -1.0))
        .animate(controller);
  }
```

And on button tap I trigger this animation and move to another page:

```
Navigator.push( context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SearchPage()),;
```

However, I want to reset animation from first page (`HomePage( )`) when back button is pressed.

How can I get this `controller` property from `SearchPage`? Probably I have to do `controller.reset()` or there is another way?

Comment: **Navigator.push()** method is a future that resolves when **Navigator.pop()** is called. So you can "await" for the Navigator.push, then reset your animation or do any other stuff you want
Hope this helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Page1 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _Page1State createState() => _Page1State();
}

class _Page1State extends State<Page1> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _controller;
  Animation<Offset> _offset;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500));
    _offset = Tween<Offset>(begin: Offset.zero, end: Offset(0.0, -10.0)).animate(_controller);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Page 1")),
      body: Center(
        child: SlideTransition(
          position: _offset,
          child: RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () async {
              await _controller.forward();
              Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => Page2())).then(
                (_) => _controller.reverse(), // this is all you need, you can also use reset here
              );
            },
            child: Text("Navigate"),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Page2 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(context) => Scaffold(appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Page 2")));
}
```